# AngularJS with Closure Compiler - Simple Optimizations Fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please shed light on why simple optimizations are failing for me in AngularJS?  More importantly, how can I get them to work?  (best practice/clarification for defining controllers is welcome too).

Here's my scenario, greatly simplified.

I'm using this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html ng-app="">
  <head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="simple_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    //inline JS here
    $(function() {
        var spinner = $( "#qtySpinner" ).spinner({
            spin: function( event, ui ) {
                scope.qty = ui.value;
                scope.$digest();
                //console.log( event );
            }
        }); //end spinner

        var scope = angular.element(spinner).scope();
    });
    </script>
    <title>Angular Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="InvoiceCntl">
      <b>Invoice:</b><br>
      <br>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Quantity
          </td>
          <td>
            Cost
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="qtySpinner" type="integer" min="0" ng-model="qty" required="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="cost" required="">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr>
      <b>Total:</b> {{calculate(qty,cost)}}
    </div>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I'm using this highly minification proof (I thought) JS file as "simple_script.js", which actually works as is:

```
//this works
window["InvoiceCntl"] = function ($scope) {
   $scope["qty"] = 1;
   $scope["cost"] = 19.95;
   $scope["calculate"] = function (xval, yval) {
                            return xval * yval;
                         };
}
```

Minified using Google Closure Compiler (http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS, I get this, which breaks:

```
//this breaks, seemingly because "a" replaces "$scope"?
window.InvoiceCntl=function(a){a.qty=1;a.cost=19.95;a.calculate=function(a,b){return a*b}};
```

I presume it's because `$scope` is a key word Angular looks for (Dependency Injection?), because when I add the extra step, manually, of passing `$scope` and assigning it to `a` in the first line of the function, it works.  Like so:

```
//manually passing "$scope" and immediately assigning it to "a" works
window.InvoiceCntl=function($scope){var a=$scope;a.qty=1;a.cost=19.95;a.calculate=function(a,b){return a*b}};
```

- Why doesn't `$scope` behave like a normal function parameter in this situation?
- Is there a way to minify (simple or advanced) angular code using Closure compiler (or something else) without a manual step like this?
- Is `$scope` configurable or is it a fixed key word, i.e., could I changed the key word to "$myscope" when I'm defining the controller?  (not sure that helps me anyway)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

I think your concern about injecting '$scope' is correct.
You can inject like following.

```
var module = angular.module('youApp', []);
module.controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope["something"] = "somevalue";
})];
```

**Edit:** The minification renames `$scope`, you can prevent this by adding:

```
InvoiceCntl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Comment: your answer pointed me in the right direction, so thanks.  The most relevant section at that link is titled "A Note on Minification," which describes how to inject the literal '$scope' explicitly, a la `PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];`.  Your code is equally correct, and there's a section in the tutorial somewhere (can't find it at the moment) that describes the 3 ways to properly declare them: `$inject` (as I wrote), your suggestion (which is like shorthand for `$inject`, and the basic way that's shown in all the examples (and my initial question).